# Function that creates nested list from text file, python

Tags: python, list

Working on a function that takes lines of texts and turns them into an inner list based 
on a space between the blocks. The code works for all but the very last chunk, which it ignores or something.

Code:

```
def build_grocery_list(grocery_file):
    food_list = []
    inner_list = []
    for line in grocery_file:
        if line.strip() == "":
            food_list.append(inner_list)
            inner_list = []            
        if line.strip() != "":
            inner_list.append(line.strip())

    return food_list
```

returns: `[['milk', 'cheese', 'cream cheese', 'eggs'], ['bread', 'buns', 'pita'], ['hamburgers', 'hotdogs', 'chicken'], ['chicken soup', 'canned tuna']]`

missing the last block :`lettuce, cabbage`

Comment: Can you post the contents of `grocery_file`?

Comment: can you show us the text file?

Comment: how would I post it? Look at each nested list as 3 individual lines. when a new nested list starts there was a space between the last element of the list before the first element of next

Comment: unrelated python style hint: `if line.strip():` is equivalent to `if line.strip != ""`, ie, python reads an empty string as False

Comment: Oh interesting! Does that work for anytime we try and call something that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an empty line at the end of the text file it will work. If not it never appends the last inner_list. Just add a check and append after you exit the loop.

```
def build_grocery_list(grocery_file):
    food_list = []
    inner_list = []
    for line in grocery_file:
        if line.strip() == "":
            food_list.append(inner_list)
            inner_list = []            
        if line.strip() != "":
            inner_list.append(line.strip())
    if (inner_list):
        food_list.append(inner_list)

    return food_list
```

Comment: Oh great point!The function doesn't even bother to execute that chunk. Thanks for explaining as well as answering.